# Running Java code from IntelliJ which runs python code and needs virtualenv

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea, virtualenv

I'm running (and debugging) Java code from IntelliJ.
This code runs some python code which needs to be run from a specific Virtualenv.

I couldn't find an option to set up a virtualenv from IntelliJ IDEA, there is any workaround I could go for?

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks a lot

Comment: Why can't you create a virtual env on your code (I assume this env changes? or standalone). Just replace the python script shebang line to the path of your env created by your java code. "#!/Users/foo/environments/project/env/bin/python"

https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/#creating-a-virtualenv

Comment: I'm using the Jep library on Java, I don't see how that can be made.
@SiddarthSreeni do you mean by system.exec the virtualenv activation from Java before running the python code? I'm not really sure that would work....

Comment: I dont know what purpose you are trying to achieve from the same although, I believe can you elaborate your Q